# Adding an explicit constraint on the action space in an openAI gym environment

Tags: python, openai-gym

I'm defining a custom environment in openAI's gymnasium library. The action space is a vector defined as a "box" space. I want to add a constraint where the sum of the value of every 3 indexes within the vector must be less than a certain number. Ex. I have the following vector: vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. I want to add a constraint such that sum of vector[0:3] < constraint and vector[3: 6] < constraint and vector[6:9] < constraint. Is there a possibility to impose this constraint on the environment? Where would this be done? Would I have to override the Box space's sample function?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I came up with is constrained reinforcement learning implemented e.g. in [Bullet Safety Gym](https://github.com/SvenGronauer/Bullet-Safety-Gym) where violation of the constrained is allowed but will be "trained out". And to quote their [technical report](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/1639974) four learning algorithms that implement this requirement:

> • TRPO-L applies a Lagrangian relaxation to the TRPO objective,
> transforming the constraint problem to an equivalent unconstrained one
> which accounts for cost violations. The Lagrange multiplier is a
> learnable and stateful variable to trade-off rewards and costs.
>
> • Constrained Policy Optimization (CPO) [1](https://github.com/SvenGronauer/Bullet-Safety-Gym) optimizes the trust-region
> problem and determines the Lagrange multiplier for constraint
> satisfaction from scratch at each policy update step. We use a
> simplified version without cost shaping similarly to [28].
>
> • Primal-dual Optimization (PDO) uses as a learnable and stateful
> Lagrange multiplier that is used to trade off reward and cost
> gradients in a trust-region update step. Our implementation follows
> [1](https://github.com/SvenGronauer/Bullet-Safety-Gym).
>
> • Projection-based Constrained Policy Optimization (PCPO) is an
> extension to CPO that optimizes the policy objective in two steps. The
> first step is an unconstrained parameter update while the second step
> regards constraint violations by projecting the policy back onto the
> constraint set

I'd be really interested if you found something that always enforces the constraints not just as a result of training.